# How to go back to the beginning of the while loop in my quiz

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

This is a quiz that I have made that asks users to translate arabic words in to english. When the user reaches the end of the quiz, it asks if the user would like to play again. If the user inputs the word **yes** then quiz should **restart.** I need help on making this loop restart when the user says yes.

The code is listed below:

```
import time
x = 0
print("Welcome to the Arabic Vocabulary Test...")
print("Loading...")
time.sleep(1)
correct = 0

import random
words = ["بىت","مسجد","باب","كتب","قلم","مفت ح","مكتب","سرير","كرسي"]
while x <9:
    quest = random.choice(words)
    print("What is" , quest, "?" )
    words.remove(quest)
    ans = input()
    x = x+1
    if quest == "بىت" and ans == "a house":
        print("Correct")
        correct = correct + 1
    elif quest == "مسجد" and ans == "a mosque":
        print("Correct")
        correct = correct + 1
    elif quest == "باب" and ans == "a door":
        print("correct")
        correct = correct + 1
    elif quest == "كتب" and ans == "a book":
        print("correct")
        correct = correct + 1
    elif quest == "قلم" and ans == "a pen":
        print("correct")
        correct = correct + 1
    elif quest == "مفت ح" and ans == "a key":
        print("correct")
        correct = correct + 1
    elif quest == "مكتب" and ans == "a table":
        print("Correct")
        correct = correct + 1
    elif quest == "سرير" and ans == "a bed":
        print("correct")
        correct = correct + 1
    elif quest == "كرسي" and ans == "a chair":
        print("correct")
        correct = correct + 1
    else:
            print("Incorrect")


print("You got" ,correct , "out of 9.")
print("")
print("Check your answers")

print('''a house = "بىت"
a mosque = "مسجد"
a door = "باب"
a book = "كتب"
a pen = "قلم"
a key = "مفت ح"
a table = "مكتب"
a bed = "سرير"
a chair = "كرسي" 
''')
again = input("Would you like to play again?: ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your code in a function and call it inside a while loop:

```
def quiz():
    // the quiz code here

while True:
    quiz()
    again = input("Would you like to play again?: ")
    if again != "yes":
        # If the answer is not `yes`, stop the loop
        break
```

By the way, some comment about your quiz code :)

- You can use a dictionary to put the words and their answer:

  ```
  words = {
      "بىت" : "a house",
      "مسجد" : "a mosque",
      ...
  }
  ```
- Then, an alternative way to code quiz would be:

  ```
  def quiz():
      # Get the list of words
      questions = words.keys()
      # Shuffle the questions
      random.shuffle(questions)
      count = 0
      for quest in questions:
          ans = input()
          # Check the answer in the dict
          if ans == words[quest]:
              count += 1
              print("Correct")
          else:
              print("Incorrect")

      print("You got", count, "out of", len(questions), ".")
      print("")
      print("Check your answers")
      # Print the keys and values of the `words` dictionary
      for word, value in words.items():
          print(word, "=", value)
  ```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

Include all the quiz code inside the while loop. If the user would like to play again, simply just reset your counter, "x", to 0.

```
temp_words = words
while x <9:
    quest = random.choice(temp_words)
    print("What is" , quest, "?" )
    temp_words.remove(quest)
    ans = input()
    x = x+1
    if quest == "بىت" and ans == "a house":
        print("Correct")
        correct = correct + 1
    elif quest == "مسجد" and ans == "a mosque":
        print("Correct")
        correct = correct + 1
    elif quest == "باب" and ans == "a door":
        print("correct")
        correct = correct + 1
    elif quest == "كتب" and ans == "a book":
        print("correct")
        correct = correct + 1
    elif quest == "قلم" and ans == "a pen":
        print("correct")
        correct = correct + 1
    elif quest == "مفت ح" and ans == "a key":
        print("correct")
        correct = correct + 1
    elif quest == "مكتب" and ans == "a table":
        print("Correct")
        correct = correct + 1
    elif quest == "سرير" and ans == "a bed":
        print("correct")
        correct = correct + 1
    elif quest == "كرسي" and ans == "a chair":
        print("correct")
        correct = correct + 1
    else:
            print("Incorrect")


    print("You got" ,correct , "out of 9.")
    print("")
    print("Check your answers")

    print('''a house = "بىت"
    a mosque = "مسجد"
    a door = "باب"
    a book = "كتب"
    a pen = "قلم"
    a key = "مفت ح"
    a table = "مكتب"
    a bed = "سرير"
    a chair = "كرسي" 
    ''')
    again = input("Would you like to play again?: ")

    if again is 'yes':
        x = 0
        temp_words = words
```